# Using a .desktop entry for a Virtualbox VM to launch from Unity launcher still opens Virtualbox

Tags: unity, virtualbox, .desktop, virtualization, launcher

I have two VMs with Virtualbox. I create for each a .desktop entry like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My VM
Comment=
Exec=VBoxManage startvm 'My VM Name'
Icon=/home/myuser/VirtualBox VMs/my-vm-icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

Then I dragged the .desktop file to the Unity launcher and it is correctly attached there with its icon. Nice.

If I click on the icon though, to boot the VM, Virtualbox opens, the Virtualbox icon appears on the Unity launcher and I can only access my VM from there. How to avoid this? I'd like to keep only the entry associated with my .desktop entry and not show Virtualbox from Unity.

Comment: Haven't tested it, but try the starting your machine with the qt frontend - `VirtualBox --startvm 'My VM Name'`.

Comment: that worked! good guess! if you add it as an answer I will mark it as correct, thank you

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (tested VirtualBox 6.1)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to what adonis suggested in the comment , you could give full path to the virtual machine as argument to `VirtualBox` command. In other words, the exec line , for my 15.10 Ubuntu VM could look like this:

```
Exec=VirtualBox  "/home/Serg/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu 15.10/Ubuntu 15.10.vbox"
```

Comment: Correct, That's How I use to do it too :) Easier to remember as well :)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (tested VirtualBox 6.1)